# Filtering spark tbl in a loop

Tags: r, dplyr, sparklyr, tibble

I am using `sparklyr` with `dplyr` to read data of size much greater than the available RAM. So, I didn't load the data to memory.

```
dat_tbl <- spark_read_parquet(sc, name = "dat", path = path, memory = FALSE)
```

When I tried to filter (the data in side a loop, say `i = 1`) in the following manner, it **failed**

```
var_name <- unique_values$Species[1]
res <- dat_tbl %>%
             filter(Species ==  unique_values$Species[1])
res
```

> Error in UseMethod("escape") : 
>     no applicable method for 'escape' applied to an object of class "c('tbl_df', 'tbl', 'data.frame')"

However, **the following is successful!**

```
var_name <- unique_values$name[1]
res <- dat_tbl %>%
             filter(Species ==  var_name)
```

I am wondering why!?

**EDIT**

Here's a small reproducible example.

```
library(sparklyr)
library(dplyr)

# setting up
sc <- spark_connect(master = "local")
iris_tbl <- copy_to(sc, iris)
spark_write_parquet(iris_tbl, "temp")

tbl <- spark_read_parquet(sc, "data", "temp")

unique_values <- tbl %>% distinct(Species) %>% collect
unique_values$Species[1]
#[1] "versicolor"
class(unique_values$Species[1])
#[1] "character"

res <- tbl %>% filter(Species ==  unique_values$Species[1] )
res
# Error in UseMethod("escape") : 
#   no applicable method for 'escape' applied to an object of 
#   class "c('tbl_df', 'tbl', 'data.frame')"

var_name <- unique_values$Species[1]
res <- tbl %>% filter(Species ==   var_name)
res

# # Source: spark<?> [?? x 5]
#    Sepal_Length Sepal_Width Petal_Length Petal_Width Species   
#           <dbl>       <dbl>        <dbl>       <dbl> <chr>     
#  1          7           3.2          4.7         1.4 versicolor
#  2          6.4         3.2          4.5         1.5 versicolor
#  3          6.9         3.1          4.9         1.5 versicolor
#  4          5.5         2.3          4           1.3 versicolor
#  5          6.5         2.8          4.6         1.5 versicolor
```

Comment: Can you show a reproducible example?

Comment: @Rohit I've managed a reproducible example.

Comment: It seems like it might be a bug. I suggest going through their github if you're interested: https://github.com/rstudio/sparklyr/issues might be something there

Answer (score 1):

Although this isn't a full answer, the problem occurs in translating the `dplyr` expression to `SQL`.

**Fails**

```
tbl %>% filter(Species ==  unique_values$Species[1] ) %>% show_query()

#<SQL>
```

> Error in UseMethod("escape") : 
>     no applicable method for 'escape' applied to an object of class "c('tbl_df', 'tbl', 'data.frame')"

**Works**

```
var_name <- unique_values$Species[1]
tbl %>% filter(Species ==  var_name) %>% show_query()
#<SQL>
#SELECT *
#FROM `data`
#WHERE (`Species` = "versicolor")
```